# Replacing Data in a function through parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a few javascript codes with the D3 graph and Rickshaw framework implementation. In that I observe that one particular value passed through a function to replace the value in it.

The below code inside the function - func()

```
 graph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
              element : document.getElementById("scatterchart"),
              renderer : 'scatterplot',
              height : 260,
              width : 680,
              series : [{
                     data : data,
                     color : color,
                     name : name
              }]
       });
```

so In the code the 'data' value inside the series, It is replaced like,

`fuc({data : replacedData})`.

I observe that it is replacing the 'data'. But I am not understanding what method exactly it is. Please help me out!

Comment: I had no errors. I just want to know how it can be done. And how exactly it works.

Comment: So you pass in an object, the object's data field is modified, and you want to know how it was modified?

Comment: Sorry If my question is not clear. I am new to Jquery. And exactly yes.. I want to know how exactly it is finding the data and replacing the "replacedData" into it..

Comment: There is no JQuery in your code snippet by the way. You are passing in an object as the function's parameter. You may update that object anytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this clear, you can rewrite your code as follows:

```
var parameters = {
    element : document.getElementById("scatterchart"),
    renderer : 'scatterplot',
    height : 260,
    width : 680,
    series : [{
                data : data,
                color : color,
                name : name
             }]
};

graph = new Rickshaw.Graph(parameters);
```

So you first create an object, then pass it in as a parameter to your function. Since objects in JavaScript are mutable, you can edit any property of the object anytime as such:

```
parameters.height = 10000;
```

or

```
parameters.series[0].data = null;
```

To also clarify the [object literal notation](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php), `[]` denote arrays, `{}` denote dictionaries or also known as associative arrays, maps, hash maps, etc.